# Why $\nabla f = O(\frac{1}{|x|^2})$?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

For $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$, let
$$ f(x) = \log |x| - \log |x - 2e_2|, $$
where $e_2 = (0,1)^T$ is the standard unit vector.

It is said that the second logarithm term above is to ensure that $\nabla f$ has better decay at $x = \infty$, namely $\nabla f = O(\frac{1}{|x|^2})$. I think it has something to do with the expansion of $\nabla f$, but I don't quite get it.

Can someone please help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is $|x|^2 = x_1^2 + x_2^2$? If so why don't you just try differentiating this and see what it looks at for $|x| \to \infty$?

Comment: @Gregory I got $\nabla f = \frac{x}{|x|^2} - \frac{x-2e_2}{|x-2e_2|^2}$. How can I find its behavior at $x = \infty$? It doesn't look like $O(\frac{1}{|x|^2})$ to me.

Comment: Looks good to me, the behavior seems to be $1/|x|$.

Comment: Maybe it is an error in the solution.

Comment: @Gregory This is in the paper I'm reading, and it was confirmed that this is not a typo. I'm not sure if I miss anything here.

Comment: Well you can assume that $|x - 2 e_2| \approx |x|$ for $|x| \gg 1$ and then you end up with $\nabla f \approx \frac{1}{|x|^2}$ for large $|x|$.

Comment: Instead of assuming $|x-2e_2|\approx |x|$, write out what each of those mean (i.e. $|x-2e_2|^2=x\cdot x -4x\cdot e_2 +4$), find a common denominator, and simplify. You'll end up with $O(|x|^2)$ in the numerator and $O(|x|^4)$ in the denominator after canceling terms.

Comment: @ColeStiegler Thank you very much for your explanation.

Comment: @Gregory Your explanation is also great too. I learned something new!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it might be useful to present a way forward that admits a general approach.  To that end, we proceed.

Using the binomial theorem we can write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{|\vec x-2\hat e_2|^2}&=\left((\vec x-2\hat e_2)\cdot (\vec x-2\hat e_2)\right)^{-1}\\\\
&=\left(|\vec x|^2 -4\hat e_2\cdot \vec x+4\right)^{-1}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{|\vec x|^2}\left(1-4\frac{\hat e_2\cdot \hat x}{|\vec x|}+4\frac{1}{|\vec x|^2}\right)^{-1}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{|\vec x|^2}\left(1+4\frac{\hat e_2\cdot \hat x}{|\vec x|}+O\left(\frac{1}{|\vec x|^2}\right) \right)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{|\vec x|^2}+4\frac{\hat e_2\cdot \hat x}{|\vec x|^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{|\vec x|^4}\right)\tag1
\end{align}$$

Therefore, for $f=\log(|\vec x|)-\log(|\vec x-2\hat e_2|)$, use of $(1)$ reveals that

$$\begin{align}
\nabla f&=\frac{\vec x}{|\vec x|^2}-\frac{\vec x-2\hat e_2}{|\vec x-2\hat e_2|^2}\\\\
&=\frac{\vec x}{|\vec x|^2}-\left(\vec x-2\hat e_2 \right)\left(\frac{1}{|\vec x|^2}+4\frac{\hat e_2\cdot \hat x}{|\vec x|^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{|\vec x|^4}\right)\right)\\\\
&=\color{blue}{\underbrace{2\frac{\hat e_2}{|\vec x|^2}-4\frac{(\hat e_2\cdot\hat x)\hat x}{|\vec x|^2}}_{=O\left(\frac{1}{|\vec x|^2}\right)}}+O\left(\frac{1}{|\vec x|^3}\right)\\\\
&=O\left(\frac{1}{|\vec x|^2}\right)
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Once you have accrued enough reputation points, you can up vote answers as you see fit.